# Connecting to BigQuery in RShiny

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, shiny, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I've tried two methods to connect my Shiny app to a BigQuery table as its source data:

1. Hadley's bigrquery, and
2. Mark Edmondson's BigQueryR

They're both failing the same way, so it's clearly a DFU error.

In each case, when I execute the appropriate command to establish the authorized connection (`gar_auth_service(json_file = /path/,scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'` and `bq_auth(path = /path/`, respectively), I get this:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This error comes ***after*** what appears to be a normal Google login process in the browser. The error page is hosted at localhost:1410, if that's any help.

In the Console, I have:

1. Created a VM instance (Ubuntu 19)
2. Successfully installed R, RStudio, and Shiny
3. Successfully logged in to RStudio in my GCP instance (from the browser, obviously, using the Externa IP I reserved in GCP)

I've also already created a BigQuery table in the same project, and successfully connected to it from an R script on my local machine.

I'm trying to get that same R script to run grom my Google Compute Engine instance.

Have I provided enough details to ask for help? If not, let me know what else I should provide. I'm walking through teaching myself GCP right now, and I'm quite the novice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bypass this issue, try connecting to your Ubuntu 19 instance using [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com) on your Compute Engine instance as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine).

Chrome Remote Desktop allows you to remotely access applications with a graphical user interface from a local computer instead of using the External IP. For this approach, you don't need to open firewall ports, and you use your Google Account for authentication and authorization. I've tried and I was able to connect both Shiny Server and to the RStudio.